# Windows desktop showing or focused

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to tell if the desktop is focused or showing? I want to know if the desktop is double clicked on.

Comment: Not especially easy in .NET. "Mouse Capture" is the term you want to Google. This might help: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/359/capturing-the-mouse

Comment: If you specifically want to check if the desktop is focused I suppose you could P/Invoke [**`GetDesktopWindow()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633504(v=vs.85).aspx) and [**`GetActiveWindow()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646292(v=vs.85).aspx) and just compare the results of them.